# unauthorized status when tring to sync with CouchDB

Tags: couchdb, svelte

I'm trying to connect with CouchDB using svelte but it shows me this error

> {"status":401,"name":"unauthorized","message":"You are not authorized
> to access this db.","reason":"You are not authorized to access this
> db."}

and I think it's because allow_persistent_cookies or cookie_domain  like it shows in the document.

but I have no idea what should I do.

```
<script> 
    import List from './add.svelte';
    import '@babel/polyfill';
    import {onMount} from 'svelte'
    import PouchDB from 'pouchdb-browser';
    let db = new PouchDB('db');
    const replecate=PouchDB.sync('db',"http://127.0.0.1:5984/twd2", {
        
        live: true,
        retry: true

    }).on('change', async function(i){
        await updatoContact();
    }).on('error', async function(err){
        console.log('the error in sync is '+ err) 

    });

    let contacts=[];
    let fisrtName='';
    let phoneNume='';
    
    export let name;
    async function addContact(event){
         
        const newContact = {
             name: fisrtName,
              phone: phoneNume
         } 
        
         // console.log(newContact);
         const sendtoDB = await db.post(newContact); 

         if(sendtoDB.ok) {
             await updatoContact();
         }



        fisrtName = ""; 
        phoneNume ="";
    }
async function updatoContact(){
    
    const allContact = await db.allDocs({
        include_docs:true 
    });
    contacts=allContact.rows.map(rows =>rows.doc);
    console.log(contacts);

}


onMount (async() => {
    await updatoContact();
})

</script>
```

Comment: Where and how are the credentials being set up?

Comment: credentials set to true

Comment: cors-credentials-true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find a solution for making a fetch request to get the session like this.

```
fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5984/_session", {
     method: "POST",

     body: JSON.stringify({
      name: "admin",
      password: "123"
     
  }),

     headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
  }
})
```

https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/server/authn.html